# Unity Can not build after updating to editor 2021.3.4f1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

After upgrading to editor 2021.3.4f1 , I started to get the errors below when building the app

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\ManagedStripped failed with output:

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe --search-directory=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --out=Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/ManagedStripped --include-link-xml=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\MethodsToPreserve.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\TypesInScenes.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\SerializedTypes.xml --include-link-xml=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\MEGAsync Downloads\TRAFFIC.IO\Traf\Temp\burst.link.xml --include-link-xml=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\MEGAsync Downloads\TRAFFIC.IO\Traf\Assets\UnityAds\link.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/AndroidNativeLink.xml --include-directory=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --dotnetruntime=Il2Cpp --platform=Android --use-editor-options --enable-engine-module-stripping --engine-modules-asset-file=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/modules.asset --editor-data-file=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/EditorToUnityLinkerData.json --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/ToonyColorsPro2.Demo.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/KinoBloom.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Unity.RenderPipelines.Core.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/ToonyColorsPro.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/DELL/Documents/MEGAsync Downloads/TRAFFIC.IO/Traf/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/TextMeshPro-2017.3-Runtime.dll --print-command-line

Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker

Mono.Linker.LinkerFatalErrorException: ILLink: error IL1005: TMPro.TMP_InputField.CreateCursorVerts(): Error processing method 'TMPro.TMP_InputField.CreateCursorVerts()' in assembly 'TextMeshPro-2017.3-Runtime.dll'

 ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve UnityEngine.Vector2 UnityEngine.UIVertex::uv0

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedField(FieldReference reference)

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldReference reference, DependencyInfo reason)

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction, MethodDefinition method, Boolean& requiresReflectionMethodBodyScanner)

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)

   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)

   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()

   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)

   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)

   at Unity.Linker.UnityPipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)

   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)

   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(Boolean noProfilerAllowed, ILogger customLogger)

   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(ILogger customLogger, Boolean noProfilerAllowed)

   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

> BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
>
> UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
> <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
>
> UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
>
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> :0)
>
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
> (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
> target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath,
> System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32
> width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options,
> UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry,
> UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Comment: Looks like you might be using an older version of TMP than is supported in this version of unity.  Try importing the newest version of TMP and see if that resolves the issue.  Source: `Error processing method 'TMPro.TMP_InputField.CreateCursorVerts()' in assembly 'TextMeshPro-2017.3-Runtime.dll'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the error above is:

> Error processing method 'TMPro.TMP_InputField.CreateCursorVerts()' in assembly 'TextMeshPro-2017.3-Runtime.dll'

Which means that this version of `TextMeshPro` (2017.3) is incompatible with the unity version you upgraded to.

Updating the TMP dll should resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks ! it fixed the issue , I also had to manualy remove the old TMP to avoid conflict